# why the value of input is not set on click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, django-templates

I am using django framework for making attendance app.
There is dropdown for attendance id user select absent than it call a function than the hidden input box set the value of absent.
this is my template

```
<form action="/index" method="POST">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            {% for staffs in staff %}
                                                <input type="hidden" name="staff_id{{staffs.id}}" value="{{staffs.id}}">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="attendance{{staffs.id}}" id='input_attendance{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td> {{staffs.id}} </td>
                                                    <td> {{staffs.name}} </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id='present{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                                Present
                                                            </button>
                                                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                                                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="attendance_present({{staffs.id}})">Present</a>
                                                                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="attendance_absent({{staffs.id}})">Absent</a>
                                                                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="attendance_half_day({{staffs.id}})">Half-day</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td> {{staffs.role}} </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                
                                            {% endfor %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <button type="submit" style="float:right" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                                            </tr>
                                        </form>
<script>
        function attendance_present(id) {
            let per = '#present' + id
            document.querySelector(per).textContent = "Present"
            document.querySelector(per).classList.remove("btn-outline-danger")
            document.querySelector(per).classList.remove("btn-outline-warning")
            document.querySelector(per).classList.add("btn-outline-primary")

            let input_attendance = 'input_attendance' + id
            document.queryselector(input_attendance).value = "present"
        }

        function attendance_absent(id) {
            let per = '#present' + id
            document.querySelector(per).textContent = "Absent"
            document.querySelector(per).classList.remove("btn-outline-primary")
            document.querySelector(per).classList.remove("btn-outline-warning")
            document.querySelector(per).classList.add("btn-outline-danger")

            let input_attendance = 'input_attendance' + id
            document.queryselector(input_attendance).value = "absent"
        }

        function attendance_half_day(id) {
            let per = '#present' + id
            document.querySelector(per).textContent = "Half-day"
            document.querySelector(per).classList.remove("btn-outline-primary")
            document.querySelector(per).classList.remove("btn-outline-danger")
            document.querySelector(per).classList.add("btn-outline-warning")

            let input_attendance = 'input_attendance' + id
            document.queryselector(input_attendance).value = "half-day"
        }
</script>
```

but is is not setting up the value the main code is

```
<input type="hidden" name="attendance{{staffs.id}}" id='input_attendance{{staffs.id}}'>
<script>
function attendance_absent(id) {

        let input_attendance = 'input_attendance' + id
        document.queryselector(input_attendance).value = "absent"
    }
</script>
```

here the {{staffs.id}} is coming from django table.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer
here, I use queryselector but i wanted to set it from id, js is not able to find, the answer is

```
document.queryselector(input_attendance).value = "absent"

document.getElementById(input_attendance).value = "absent"
```